# Ruby on Rails Undefined method find_by_email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, controller

I have a weird issue, I can't seem to `find_by_email` working in my project, here's the part of my controller where I'm getting the exception. I am using rails `4.0.3`

```
def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Welcome back!"
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Email or password is invalid"
      render "new"
    end
end
```

I can't stop anything wrong with the code but still getting Action Controller: Exception caught:

```
NoMethodError in SessionsController#create
app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:6:in `create'
undefined method `find_by_email' for #<Class:0x007fbdd62179b0>
```

I'm wondering if there was another way I could troubleshoot this? I've tried using the method manually in the rails console but receive the same issue.

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using?

Comment: `User` table have email field?

Comment: Make sure you have `email` field in your users table.

Comment: For Rails4, use `find_by(:email => params[:email])`

Comment: @Santosh I'm using Rails 4.0.3

Comment: @Santosh I've update my controller but I get a different error now SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.email: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" IS NULL LIMIT 1

Comment: Have you created migration for `users` table?

Comment: It seems you are not having an `email` field in users table.Please cross check again

Comment: @Santosh Thanks! yes it was a migration which I forgot to run, such a silly mistake, I have updated my controller to use the new find_by as well.

Comment: @Santosh post answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by many, this is due to missing `email` column in users table.

If you have not run migrations yet, please do it.

Answer (score 0):

Add email field in users table

Rails 4.1.0 will depreciate custom find by method

Use

```
 User.find_by email: params[:email]
```

Sooner or later you have to change it.

reference

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by

Comment: this just show deprecation message but functional still, this not op problem.

Comment: add email field in users table